# Arrangements of BUBBLELICIOUS

Tags: combinatorics

> How many arrangements are possible in which no two $B$'s are next to
>   each other?

I am approaching this problem by considering the complement.

**Case 1:** $BB$ is one letter. This leaves us with $1B, 2U, 2L, 1E, 2I, 1C, 1O, 1S $($12$ letters total)

Step  1: Place $BB$: $12$ ways

Step 2: Place the third $B$ such that it is not consecutive with $BB$. **Is this step necessary? This would be split into two cases itself. One where BB is on the ends and one where BB is in the middle**

**Case 2:** $BBB$ is one letter.

**FINAL ATTEMPT:**

The total number of arrangements of the $13$ letters in BUBBLELICIOUS is $\displaystyle\frac{13!}{3!(2!)^3}$.

Consider the complement. Consider $BB$ as one letter. Then there are $\displaystyle\frac{12!}{(2!)^3}$ ways to arrange the letters.

So there are $\displaystyle\frac{13!}{3!(2!)^3}-\displaystyle\frac{12!}{(2!)^3}$ arrangements where $BB$ is considered one letter.

However, we have counted twice where $BBB$ occurs. So we need to add this case back once.

Consider $BBB$ as one letter. The total number of arrangements in this case is $\displaystyle\frac{11!}{(2!)^3}$.

So the total number of arrangements in which no two $B$'s are next to each other is:

$$\displaystyle\frac{13!}{3!(2!)^3}-\displaystyle\frac{12!}{(2!)^3}+\displaystyle\frac{11!}{(2!)^3}$$

**Link to part (b) of problem: [Arrangements of BUBBLELICIOUS with no two consonants next to each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957173/arrangements-of-bubblelicious-with-no-two-consonants-next-to-each-other)**

Comment: There is the issue of counting twice the words where $BBB$ appears. Once as $(BB)B$ and another time as $B(BB)$.

Comment: how do i account for this...i am stuck after step 1 of placing $BB$. @SaucyO'Path

Comment: You'll have counted them twice, so you just need to subtract the number of ways all three B's can come together.  That's where your case 2 comes in.

Comment: oh! okay...does step 2 have to be split into two cases though? as i've asked above @saulspatz

Comment: No, just count the ways to arrange the letters, where one pair of B's is counted as a single letter.  You have 12 letters, including three pairs.

Comment: @saulspatz so step 2 would just be to arrange the remaining 12 letters, accounting for the repeated letters?

Comment: Sure.  That way, you're ensuring that at least 2 B's come together.

Comment: @saulspatz my final attempt is edited into my answer above, if you would not mind checking

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: @saulspatz would you mind taking a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957173/arrangements-of-bubblelicious-with-no-two-consonants-next-to-each-other

Comment: I'm slightly confused because wouldn't this answer over count? I ask because in the case in which BB is considered one letter, can't the third B appear next to this BB, thus making it a BBB? Having said this, you would be over counting (double counting some of the arrangements in the case with the block of BBB). I may be wrong though...

Answer (score 1):

I asked a different question because of this.  My strategy is to first count all ways of arranging the B's without any being adjacent.  If you use the relationship [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2957752/497388), this is $\binom{13-3+1}{3}$.  After placing the B's, there are 10 letters left, for $10!$ placements; however, we must remove double counting of I's, U's, and L's (divide by 2 for each one), giving the result $$\binom{11}{3}\frac{10!}{8}$$