# prove that $b$ balls can be placed in $\binom{n-b+1}{b}$ spaces without touching

Tags: combinatorics, induction

There are several questions (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2957110/497388)) that involve counting the ways that $b$ balls can be placed into $n$ spaces such that no balls are adjacent, for instance $B\_ B\_ B\_ $ but not $ BB\_ B\_\, \_$.  I've been playing with this, and found that the formula $$
\binom{n-b+1}{b}$$seems to work, but I don't know how to prove this.  Additionally, I don't understand the intuition behind it.

I thought of induction on b:  Assume $\binom{n-b+1}{b}$ holds for $b$ balls.  If we place $b-1$ balls in left to right order, we notice that the ways to place the $b$th ball declines by one for each new ordering, creating a triangular arrangement.  For instance, $n=5$, $b=2$ gives $ B\_ x x x$, $\_ B\_ xx$, and $\_\,\_ B\_ x$ where $x$ is possible placements of the second ball.

Adding another ball into the mix effectively removes the largest two "diagonals" in such arrangements, but how does this become $\binom{n-b}{b+1}$?

Induction on n: you add a space, and therefore add a new "diagonal" onto each current arrangement.  Again, I'm not seeing it.

**EDIT:**

Could I assume that the base case is where the balls are precisely fixed, as in $B\_ B\_ \dots B\_ B$ where the run ends on a ball and $n=2b-1$?  In that case, there is only one arrangement, which corresponds to $$\binom{n-b+1}{b}=\binom{2b-1 - b + 1}{b}=\binom{b}{b} = 1$$  Now, add one more space to this arrangement: a space at the end, between the last pair, between the next to last pair, and so on, and one at the start, for a total of $b+1$ ways.  Now compare against $n+1$ in the relationship above, where $n+1 = 2b-1+1 = 2b$, thus $$\binom{n+1-b+1}{b}=\binom{2b-b+1}{b}=\binom{b+1}{b} = b+1$$What else must I prove?

Comment: When editing (unless you're on mobile), you can see the rendered result below the edit window before posting. That way you don't need to make comments to test things out.

Comment: I was trying to get the funny box hack to work.  But then what if they fix it?  Other posts do this.  $B __ x  x x$.  Better to be safe.  Thanks - Russ

Comment: Have you taken a good look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) already?

Comment: If you want a box around it, you can do `\boxed{B\_B\_B\_}`: $\boxed{B\_B\_B\_}$

Comment: @drhab, actually, no, first I heard of it.  I just read it, and recognize the similarity in the binomial relationship, but I need some clarification on how it applies.  (In true stars and bars, the above would be $\binom{n+b-1}{n}$ not $\binom{n-b+1}{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with something like: $$n_0Bn_1Bn_2\dots n_{b-1}Bn_b$$where then $n_i$ are integers.

Here $n_0$ denotes the number of spaces on the utmost left, $n_b$ the same on the utmost right and e.g. $n_1$ the number of spaces between the first and the second ball.

Then to be found is the number of sums that satisfy $\sum_{i=0}^bn_i=n-b$ and where $n_0,n_b\geq0$ and $n_i>0$ for every other $i$.

Setting $m_0=n_0, m_b=n_b$ and $m_i=n_i-1$ for the other $i$ that comes to the same as finding the number of sums $\sum_{i=0}^bm_i=n-2b+1$ where $m_i\geq0$ for every $i$.

Then with stars and bars we find that there are:$$\binom{(n-2b+1)+b}{b}=\binom{n-b+1}{b}$$possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  What do the $m_i$ represent, and why is $m_i = n_i - 1$?

Comment: We start with $n_0+n_1+\cdots+n_b$ where the $n_i$ are positive except for $n_0$ and $n_b$. That is inconvenient. I wipe away that inconvenience by stepping over to the $m_i$. You can interpreted it as: first we put one empty spot between the balls to make them not touching anymore. After that we put in the rest of the empty spots.